# Nexus 4, ART vs Dalvik Runtime: Which provides a lower battery consumption?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-4, root-access, 4.4-kitkat, kernel

I'm using a Nexus 4 and currently using the Cyanogen Mod 11 ROM. I was using Paranoid Android Beta 4 for KitKat before but switched to Cyanogen Mod due to the stability that Cyanogen Mod offers right now.

I was wondering what are the pros and cons from ART and Dalvik. Especially since I am no longer running the Nexus 4 stock ROM. Is there any other ways of improving battery life by switching governors?

Comment: Because of the way this site works, you'll get better answers if you keep yourself to one question per post. As things stand, if someone knows about ART but don't have a suggestion about governors, they probably won't answer your question.

Comment: As with @DanHulme's answer, I suggest you remove the last sentence, and ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Over all, I think this is a valid question: All other things constant, would using ART consume lesser battery compared to using Dalvik?

Answer (score 1):

The new ART runtime is still **experimental**. It will make your phone less stable, and some apps just won't work at all. That's why the option to switch from Dalvik to ART is in the developer options: it's only there to let developers and system integrators test their stuff and help Google fix problems.

For this reason, it's a little pointless to measure the performance of ART right now, since bugs in it might cause artificially low or high performance, even in situations where the bug doesn't occur or isn't apparent. Fixing a bug might reduce performance (increasing battery or memory use, or decreasing speed) because extra checks or a slower algorithm are needed to avoid the bug; or, it might increase performance by making some computation unnecessary. Also, further work on improving the performance of ART will certainly be done before it's turned on for everybody.

Combining the effects of fixing all bugs, and all the performance improvements that are made, it's very hard to predict how the finished product will perform. The performance could completely change before ART is ready for mainstream use.

Comment: Its going to be activated in the next release of android [soon](http://www.androidauthority.com/art-aosp-commit-341520/) as reported by Android Authority.

Comment: It _might_ make your phone less stable.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, very few apps properly support ART. So, the performance difference is not really noticeable. As for battery consumption, there should be little to no difference if your CPU settings are left at default.

ART is a great innovation, and I can't wait to see some great performance numbers in the near future, but we are not there yet.

If you're running CM11 nightly builds, you might see some poor battery life. If you do, try another kernel, such as Devil.

Comment: Where is this answering the question!